# php importing excel apostrophe symbol issues

Tags: php, excel, import

I've got an excel importer for my website, which seems to be working fine - up until I found a row which has apostrophes, and it's trying to save the information into the database using �.

Example:

**Branches in Vava’u, Haapai, ‘Eua and Niuatoputapu**

Changes to:

**Branches in Vava�u, Haapai, �Eua and Niuatoputapu**

Is there any way I can fix this easily within php?

Comment: It will be useful to post the code that imports the excel.

Comment: The code I'm using is actually quite long to post in here.. http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/

Comment: I just want it to know what technique are you using for importing the excel file and if it possible to make the replacements that I mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the � by ' before saving in database. Sometimes MS Excel uses other chars with different codes for special chars (non printable ASCII codes).
Vava’u  -   contains `0x19` char code, use `0x27` instead
‘Eua    -   contains `0x18` char code, use `0x27` instead